# Send mail having test results generated at jenkins ui

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to send generated test results via mail. I am able to see the summary of test cases generated at jenkins ui at `http://<URL>:8080/job/<JOB_NAME>/<BUILD_NUMBER>/testReport/`.  How ever I want to send this in email, but, unable to find any solution for this. Does anyone knows how to do that??

Comment: Is there anything wrong in this question?? Don't know, why people are throwing negative response??

Comment: You need a plugin, and content set to build id.  Please follow the following link: https://www.360logica.com/blog/email-notification-in-jenkins/

Comment: This is right but unfortunetly I am using pipeline script

Comment: and ? did you step into `Pipeline Syntax` in Jenkins pipeline to get the email wrapper then use it ?  It is very helpful and self-explanatory.  Try following this: https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/sending-notifications-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

you can use "Editable Email Notification" plugin and attached the build logs